# Как аккуратно поменять метод remove() в итераторе

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, итераторы

Помогите пожалуйста правильно реализовать метод remove() для метода test6() и test7(). На даный момент работает лишь test7(), а вот test6() выбрасывает исключение. Как это исправить?

Буду всем благодарен за помощь!

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class StackImpl implements Stack {
    Object array[] = new Object[0];

    int top = -1;

    @Override
    public void push(Object element) {
        Object[] arrPush = new Object[array.length+1];

        for (int i = 0; i < arrPush.length; i++) {
            if (i == arrPush.length-1) {
                arrPush[i] = element;
            } else {
                arrPush[i] = array[i];
            }
        }

        array = new Object[arrPush.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = arrPush[i];
        }

        top++;
    }

    @Override
    public Object pop() {
        Object element = array[size()-1];

        if (top == -1) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }

        Object[] arrRemove = new Object[array.length-1];

        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < array.length; i++, j++) {
            if (i == top) {
                continue;
            } else {
                arrRemove[i] = array[i];
            }
        }

        array = new Object[arrRemove.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = arrRemove[i];
        }

        top--;
        return element;
    }

    @Override
    public Object top() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        array = new Object[0];
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return array.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Object> iterator() {
        return new IteratorImpl();
    }

    class IteratorImpl implements Iterator<Object> {
        int current = top;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            if (current < size()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Object next() {
            return array[current--];
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            top--;
            current++;

            if (current == -1) {
                throw new IllegalStateException();
            }

            Object arrRem[] = new Object[size()-1];

            for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < size(); i++) {
                if (i != current) arrRem[j++] = array[i];
            }

            array = new Object[arrRem.length];

            System.arraycopy(arrRem, 0, array, 0, arrRem.length);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (i == array.length - 1) stringBuilder.append(array[i]);
            else stringBuilder.append(array[i]).append(", ");
        }

        return "[" + stringBuilder.toString() + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test6();
        test7();
    }

    private static void test6() {

        Stack stack = new StackImpl();
        stack.push("A");
        stack.push("B");
        stack.push("C");

        Iterator it = stack.iterator();
        System.out.println(it.next());
        it.remove();
        System.out.println(it.next());
        it.remove();
        System.out.println(it.next());
        it.remove();
        System.out.println(stack);

    /* an output must be as the following:
    *************************************
    C
    B
    A
    []
    *************************************
    */
    }

    private static void test7() {

        Stack stack = new StackImpl();
        stack.push("A");
        stack.push("B");
        stack.push("C");

        Iterator it = stack.iterator();

        System.out.println(it.next());
        System.out.println(it.next());
        System.out.println(it.next());
        it.remove();
        System.out.println(stack);

        it = stack.iterator();

        System.out.println(it.next());
        it.remove();
        System.out.println(stack);

        it = stack.iterator();

        System.out.println(it.next());
        it.remove();
        System.out.println(stack);

    /* an output must be as the following:
    *************************************
    C
    B
    A
    [B, C]
    C
    [B]
    B
    []
    *************************************
    */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class IteratorImpl implements Iterator<Object> {
    int current = top;


    public boolean hasNext() {
        return current != -1;
    }


    public Object next() {
        return array[current--];
    }

    public void remove() {
        top--;
        final Object[] newArray = new Object[array.length - 1];
        int indexToRemove = current + 1;

        System.arraycopy(array, 0, newArray, 0, indexToRemove);
        System.arraycopy(array, indexToRemove + 1, newArray, indexToRemove, newArray.length - indexToRemove);

        array = newArray;
    }
}
```